# Is it necessary to use === to compare strings in Javascript or is == enough?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

I can understand why `===` is necessary when comparing numbers, booleans, empty strings, etc, due to unexpected type conversions e.g.

```
var foo = 1; 
var bar = true; 
// bar == foo => true
// bar === foo => false
```

But can  `==` ever introduce a bug when comparing a variable to a ***non-empty*** string literal?  Is it more efficient to use `==` over `===` in this case?

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: Type equality should be the same or faster: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/453277

Comment: equality operator (`===`). It checks that values are the same value and the same type. Rememeber this.

Comment: If both operands are guaranteed to be string values (and not `String` objects) then there is precisely no difference between the two operators (per spec).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been asked here a lot so I'll just let a better poster then myself answer.

Take a look here: http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2007/09/triple-equals-in-javascript.html

The 3 equal signs mean "equality without type coercion". Using the triple equals, the values must be equal in type as well.

```
0==false   // true
0===false  // false, because they are of a different type
1=="1"     // true, auto type coercion
1==="1"    // false, because they are of a different type
```

**source** [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

It is a good practice to **always** use the identity operators (`!==` and `===`) and perform type coercion manually only when you need to (e.g. `Boolean(someVar)` or `Number(someVar)`).

[A fun fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjSYG/9/).

Comment: +1 for stating the "good practice".This seems to be good article explaining why: https://2ality.com/2011/12/strict-equality-exemptions.html _"When is it OK to use == ? ... Short answer: never."_

Answer (score 1):

Well, I sort of answered it myself... 5 == "5", but 5 !== "5", which might be unexpected. I'll give credit to anyone who has a deeper insight though.

Answer (score 0):

the "==" does a type conversion before the comparing is done. That's the reason why 5 == "5" is true and not false.

The "===" instead does not this conversion so that 5 === "5" is not the same as long as the type is not the same.